# Разложить арккосинус на ряды Тейлора

Tags: c#, ряды

Вычислить и вывести на экран в виде таблицы значения функции, заданной с помощью ряда Тейлора, на интервале от xнач до xкон с шагом dx с точностью е. Таблицу снабдить заголовком и шапкой. Каждая строка таблицы должна содержать значение аргумента, значение функции и количество просуммированных членов ряда.

```
double xStart = -1.0; // Начальное значение x
double xEnd = 1.0; // Конечное значение x
double dx = 0.1; // Шаг x
double arcos;



Console.WriteLine("Аргумент\tЗначение функции\tКоличество слагаемых");
Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------");

for (byte n = 1; xStart <= xEnd; n++)
{
    arcos = Math.PI / 2 - (xStart + ((2 * n - 1) * Math.Pow(xStart, 2 * n + 1)) / (2 * n*(2 * n + 1)));

    Console.WriteLine($"{xStart:F1}\t\t{arcos:F4}\t\t\t{n}");
    xStart += dx;
}
```

Вывод

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильно ли я реализовал ??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: арккосинус единицы должен быть 0, так что неправильно. И почему у вас количество слагаемых линейно зависит от аргумента? И где учитывается точность?

Comment: Правильно ли вы реализовали что? С чем надо сравнивать? Источник формул и правил где? Или вы думаете, что здесь каждый по утрам ряды Тейлора раскладывает вместо утренней зарядки? :) Или отвечающему надо гуглить и изучать вопрос самостоятельно? Этот вопрос про математику или программирование? Конкретизируйте, отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте больше деталей.

Comment: @aepot, да извиняюсь, я добавил картинку с формулой

Comment: Нет, формулу вы явно неправильно реализовали. Как минимум цикл по `x` и цикл по `n` - это **два разных цикла**. А у вас только один цикл. Для каждого значения `x` вы должны отдельно вычислить значение функции, пройдя от `n=1` и пока не достигнете нужной точности. Кстати, где у вас точность `e` в коде? Похоже, её просто нету.

Comment: @CrazyElf, а можете пример привести ? А то бесконечный цикл с точностью постоянно получается (

Comment: Так добавьте исправленный код в вопрос. Можете вместо старого кода, можете в дополнение ниже как апдейт. Посмотрим в чём проблема. Кстати, модуль не забыли взять, когда точность проверяли? И сравнивать нужно очередное слагаемое ряда.

Comment: Почитайте вопросы и ответы по метке `ряды`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не усложнять решение, вынесу вычисление одного члена ряда в отдельный метод

```
static double GetMember(double x, int n)
{
    double top = 1;
    double bottom = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            top *= i;
        else
            bottom *= i;
    }
    return top * Math.Pow(x, n) / (bottom * n);
}
```

Далее, буду складывать члены, пока очередной член не уйдёт за пределы требуемой точности.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double start = -1.0;
    double end = 1.0;
    double dx = 0.1;
    double epsilon = 0.0001;

    Console.WriteLine("Аргумент\tЗначение функции\tКоличество слагаемых");
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 60));

    for (double x = start; x <= end; x += dx)
    {
        int n = 1;
        double series = 0;

        double member;
        do
        {
            member = GetMember(x, n);
            series += member;
            n += 2;
        }
        while (Math.Abs(member) >= epsilon);
        double arcos = Math.PI / 2 - series;

        Console.WriteLine($"{x:F1}\t\t{arcos:F4}\t\t\t{(n - 1) / 2}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Проверочные значения: arccos(-1)={Math.Acos(-1):F4} arccos(0)={Math.Acos(0):F4} arccos(1)={Math.Acos(1):F4}");
}
```

```
Аргумент        Значение функции        Количество слагаемых
------------------------------------------------------------
-1,0            3,0955                  151
-0,9            2,6903                  18
-0,8            2,4980                  11
-0,7            2,3461                  8
-0,6            2,2143                  6
-0,5            2,0944                  5
-0,4            1,9823                  4
-0,3            1,8755                  4
-0,2            1,7722                  3
-0,1            1,6710                  3
-0,0            1,5708                  1
0,1             1,4706                  3
0,2             1,3694                  3
0,3             1,2661                  4
0,4             1,1593                  4
0,5             1,0472                  5
0,6             0,9273                  6
0,7             0,7954                  8
0,8             0,6436                  11
0,9             0,4513                  18
1,0             0,0461                  151

Проверочные значения: arccos(-1)=3,1416 arccos(0)=1,5708 arccos(1)=0,0000
```

Увеличение точности `epsilon` выше, чем `0.0001` не даёт эффекта видимо потому что достигнут предел точности `double`. Но я детально не отлаживал, предлагаю вам самостоятельно это выяснить.

Comment: Вы, конечно, молодец, что на вопросы отвечаете, но решать за человека задание, когда он ещё толком не попробовал поднапрячься как-то как-то.

Comment: @CrazyElf вообще-то попытка решения есть. У нас нет требований к качеству попытки.